# What does the <var> syntax in Angular / Typescript mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In this line:

`getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {}`

What is the `<`variable`>`?

I've been reading through the docs, and Googling it, but Google seems to think I only want arithmetic operators. Looking for ECMA notation as well, can't find it either.

Or is it a typescript thing?

Comment: This means observable will be type of `Hero[]` being it will return observalbe array of Heroes

Comment: The concept you're looking for is [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: It is the type of the Observable. Here, you're telling your Observable that you're gonna send him an array of Hero Objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for this line of code

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {}
```

it will return `Observable` (when you see `<T>` that is syntax for [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so here in this case Observable i.e. `Obersable<Heroe[]>` ) which will give you array of `Hero` class. Observable is part of [RxJs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html).

So if you want to get value you need to `subscribe` to `observable` like as below

```
let heroes:Hero[];
this.getHeroes().subscribe( data=> heroes=data);
```

I suggest you read concept of [`Generics`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and also [`RxJs`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html), then you will get clear picture.

Comment: For a moment, let's forget about the array part. `Observable` is a class. `Hero` is a class. What's causing cognitive friction is the fact that you're telling me this returns a class A of class B. Is this type-casting the return value to Hero? Or is it setting some property of Observable to Hero? .... or ... is it decorating Hero as an Observable giving it the ability to work with the Observer design pattern?

Comment: @DrDamnit - it syntax of generic, which means you and replace T value by the type. mean if you defined generic type MyClass<T> than you can replace this T with the type either its premitive type like int,string or by userdefined type

Comment: @DrDamnit - Yes when you add Observable its observable pattern , so here when server call finish then you will get value that means you are oveserving server call

Comment: @DrDamnit - dont get me wrong but if you go to link of Generics and RXJs which is provided in answer you will able to figure it out easily

Comment: So, it decorates the `Hero` class with the `Observable` class...? Thus, making the return value a `Hero` class that can be observed by an Observer?

Comment: @DrDamnit - no overvable class decorating server call which will return Hero in future and when you subscribe for that oversable you will get return repose of server call

Answer (score 0):

This line `getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {}` represents your function, which return an `Observable` of an `array` of your `Hero` class/interface.

To get the value, you have to `subscribe` to this function and access your data through a passed callback like:

```
getHeroes().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```